# How could I check if "canplaythrough" is true?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want to show an Indicator if somebody clicks on the playbutton. If the video is loaded I want to hide the preloader. This works perfectly with readystate:

```
            var einleitung = document.getElementById('einleitung');

            video.addEventListener('play', function () {

            if ( video.readyState === 4 ) {

                myApp.hidePreloader();

            } else {

                myApp.showPreloader('Loading...');

            }

            });
```

How could I get going this with canplaythrough instead of readyState?

Something like this is not working:

```
           if ( video.canplaythrough == true ) {}
```

video.canplaythrough is "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `canplaythrough` is an `event`of not property of `audio/video` element.

This event fires only once in the lifetime of the `audio/video` element when it is totally `buffered` and can play without any `buggering`/`stop` unless `src` of the element is not changed.

It should be like this:

```
audio|video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){//your code});
```

Comment: Yes thanks. The problem is, when I use it, it works fine with the first click on play. But if I click on pause and after that on play again, the preloader is not closing again. I think the event is not firing in this case.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. That means, the only option is to work with readyState to grab the current status?

Comment: You have `play` and `pause` event to deal with!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add, a specific case for React.

I worked with someone's code in a case where the user could only play audio once for testing tools. Therefore for the best user experience, we should wait for the audio to load fully first so the user can hear the audio without pausing.

However, the `canplaythrough` or `onCanPlayThrough` event doesn't always provide the right value. I think there's a problem with the state of certain parent components that caused the child component to re-render prematurely.

My way out of this was, I create a log array that displays the events in order and add event listener to all the listener listed in MDN, also the one from my VS Code suggestion, so I can view the whole process and then tailor the app as I wanted it to be.

So if you are from React and found this, hope it helps your debugging process.